# Proc sql: new and continue customers based on look back period

Tags: sas

I have following data:

```
wei 01feb2018    car
wei 02feb2018    car
wei 02mar2019    bike
carlin 01feb2018 car
carlin 05feb2018 bike
carlin 07mar2018 bike
carlin 01mar2019 car
```

I want to identify new and continue customers, if a customer had no purchase in last 12 months then it will become a new customer. Required output be like

```
wei 01feb2018    car     new
wei 02feb2018    car     cont.
wei 02mar2019    bike    new
carlin 01feb2018 car     new
carlin 05feb2018 bike    cont.
carlin 07mar2018 bike    cont.
carlin 01mar2019 car     new
```

Now if a customer has purchased any item in the same month for ex -customer a purchased car on 01jan and bike on 15jan then I want two classify customer a as new for Jan for one report and in another report I want customer a as both new and continue.

I'm trying but not getting the logic -

```
proc sql;
select a.*,(select count(name) from t where intnx("month",-12,a.date) >= 356) 
as tot
from t a;
Quit;
```

Answer (score 1):

You appear to want two different 'status' variables, one for continuity **over** prior year and  one for continuity **within** month.

In SQL an existential reflexive correlated sub-query result can be a case test for rows meeting the **over** and **within** criteria.  Date arithmetic is used to compute days apart and `INTCK` is used to compute months apart:

```
data have; input
customer $ date& date9. item& $; format date date9.; datalines;
wei     01feb2018  car
wei     02feb2018  car
wei     02mar2019  bike
carlin  01feb2018  car
carlin  05feb2018  bike
carlin  07mar2018  bike
carlin  01mar2019  car
run;

proc sql;
  create table want as
  select *,
    case
      when exists 
      (
        select * from have as inner 
        where inner.customer=outer.customer
          and (outer.date - inner.date) between 1 and 365
      ) 
      then 'cont.'
      else 'new'
    end as status_year,
    case
      when exists 
      (
        select * from have as inner 
        where inner.customer=outer.customer
          and outer.date > inner.date
          and intck ('month', outer.date, inner.date) = 0
      ) 
      then 'cont.'
      else 'new'
    end as status_month
  from have as outer
  ;
quit;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `retain`:

```
proc sort data=test out=test2;
  by name  type date;
run;

data test2 ;
set test2;
 retain retain 'new';
 by name  type date;
   if first.type then retain='new';
   else retain='con';
run;

proc sort data=test2 out=test2;
  by name  date; 
run;
```

Output:

```
+--------+-----------+------+--------+
|  name  |   date    | type | retain |
+--------+-----------+------+--------+
| carlin | 01FEB2018 | car  | new    |
| carlin | 05FEB2018 | bike | new    |
| carlin | 01MAR2019 | car  | con    |
| wei    | 01FEB2018 | car  | new    |
| wei    | 02FEB2018 | car  | con    |
| wei    | 02MAR2019 | bike | new    |
+--------+-----------+------+--------+
```