# Perl Regex Negative Lookbehind Incorrect Match (SAS)

Tags: regex, sas, regex-lookarounds, negative-lookbehind

In SAS, I am setting up PXPARSE functions to extract meaningful information from free text answers from a survey. For the most part, I have done this without issue. However, I've started needing lookarounds and now I am getting an incorrect match despite my best efforts.

Here is the expression that is being evaluated:

```
hlhx=PRXPARSE('/yes|(?<!no).*homeless.*(for|in|year|age)|at\sage|couch|was\shomeless|multiple|
                        lived.*streets|(?<!\bnot).*at\srisk|has\sbeen|high\srisk|currently\shomeless|
                        liv(es|ing|ed).*car|many|(?<!\bno).*(hx|history|h.?o)|(?<!\bno)(?<!low).+risk/ox');
```

A couple of responses should not match this expression, but do:

- `no hx of homelessness and low risk of homelessness`
- `owns home, no h/o homelessness; low risk for homelessness`
- `no and little risk`

Obviously I have not properly specified my lookbehinds. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT: To put a finer point on it, what part of the expression is causing a match with entries like those in the list?**

Best,
Lauren

Comment: can you post the sample data and output you want to see. then it would be helpful

Comment: The list is my sample data. The output I want to see is no match. Basically, what in my expression is causing a match for the entries in the list?

Comment: if you can post sample data and output like shown in link, it will be more clear and helpful. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54976752/proc-sql-new-and-continue-customers-based-on-look-back-period

Comment: Describe your best efforts. Did it include trying a regex tool with your problem data, such as https://myregextester.com or http://refiddle.com/ where you can save and link to a saved re scenario.  I love them fiddles, waiting for SAS to do their own.

Comment: I looked at 5 or 6 regex-specific SAS tutorial papers and a number of general Perl regex documentation pages. I had tried a tester in the past, but not for this specific question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how your regex matches `no and little risk`:

One of the branches in your regex is `...|(?<!\bno)(?<!low).+risk`.

The regex engine starts by attempting a match at every position within the target string, starting at the beginning:

```
no and little risk
^
```

The first constraint is that the current position cannot be preceded by a word boundary followed by "no" (due to `(?<!\bno)`). This condition is satisfied: The beginning of the target string is not preceded by anything.

The second constraint is that the current position cannot be preceded by "low" (due to `(?<!low)`). This condition is also satisfied (see above).

Then we match one or more non-newline characters, but as many as possible of them (this is the `.+` part). Here we initially consume the whole string:

```
no and little risk
------------------^
```

But then the regex requires a match of `risk`, which fails (there are no more characters left in the target string). This causes `.+` to backtrack and consume fewer and fewer characters, until this happens:

```
no and little risk
--------------^
```

At this point, `risk` successfully matches and the regex finishes.

The basic problem is that want you want to do is `(?<!\bno.+)(?<!low.+)risk`, but what you wrote is `(?<!\bno)(?<!low).+risk`. These are two very different things!

The former means "match 'risk', but only if it's not preceded by 'no' or 'low' anywhere in the string (up to 1 character before 'risk')". The latter means "match any non-empty substring followed by 'risk', as long as it's not preceded by either 'no' or 'low'". This gives the regex engine the freedom to look for any matching position in the string, as long as it's not immediately preceded by "no" or "low" and is followed by ".+risk" somewhere.

Unfortunately `(?<!\bno.+)` is not a valid regex because look-behind assertions must have a fixed length.

One possible workaround is to do the following:

```
^(?!.*(?:\bno|low).+risk).*risk
```

This says: Starting from the beginning of the string, first make sure there is no "no" or "low" followed by "risk" anywhere, then match "risk" anywhere within the string.

This is not quite equivalent to the (hypothetical) variable-width look-behind version, because that one would have matched

```
risk no risk
^^^^
```

due to the presence of "risk" without "no" preceding it, whereas this workaround first finds

```
risk no risk
     ^^^^^^^
```

and immediately rejects the whole string.

Comment: Your explanation makes so much more sense than tutorials devoted to this sort of thing. Thank you so much for taking the time to explain how I was using the lookbehinds incorrectly. The inability to do variable length lookbehinds is very inconvenient, but it does force some creativity!